# Is there anyway to restrict FOLDER access by IP address?

Tags: security

We want to publish some Data for our team, this Data is restricted to only team members, but, we want them to access it only by 1 IP without restricting access to other folders.

Comment: What's the requirement for restricting to 1 IP? What would be wrong with having people access from other computers, so long as their user account isn't compromised?

Answer (score 0):

You can set IP restrictions at the tenant level, but there is not functionality for IP restrictions at the folder level.